# How to generate colors for unknown number of datasets in Chartjs

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I am generating a chart using react-chartjs-2 and am pulling in "categories" from my API. The number of categories is dynamic (will be between 0 and approximately 20, but ultimately it is up to the user). What is the best way to generate a different color for each slice of a doughnut chart, all based off of my primary theme color (#3B73B4)? Would it be best to just do a gradient?

My graph component is as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Doughnut } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import colors from '../_styles/colors';

class CurrentPackGraph extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        categories: props.data.categories,
    }
}

render() {
    const data = {
        labels: this.state.categories.map(c => c.name),
        datasets: [{
            data                : this.state.categories.map(i => i.items.length),
            backgroundColor     : [
                colors.darkPrimary,
                '#36A2EB',
                '#FFCE56',
            ],
            hoverBackgroundColor: [
                colors.darkPrimary,
                '#36A2EB',
                '#FFCE56',
            ],
        }],
    };

    const chartOptions = {
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
    };

    return (
        <Doughnut
            data={data}
            options={chartOptions}
            height={300}
        />
    );
  }
}

export default CurrentPackGraph;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use d3 scale library to achieve that:

```
import * as scale from "d3-scale";


// Set amount of categories
const length = 20;

// Generate color scale
const colors = scale
  .scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, length])
  .range(["#fff", "#3B73B4"]);

// define some inline styles for illustration
const getBoxStyle = color => ({
  margin: "20px",
  backgroundColor: `${color}`
});
```

And then we simply use the generated scale:

```
function App() {
  const squares = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    squares.push(
      <div style={getBoxStyle(colors(i))} key={i}>
        {colors(i)} {i}
      </div>
    );
  }

  return <div className="App">{squares}</div>;
}
```

Please see the working example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/p96vz6r5m0

Comment: The result looks exactly like what I want, however I'm curious: would importing d3-scale be another dependency that I need to add? Or does that already come with Chartjs?